# Best practice for Designing a Plugin with this scenario

Tags: plugin-development, users, html

I have a `HTML` page which I wanna use inside a `WordPress` website. But this page should be only available to users who logged-in and non logged-in users should be redirected to login page. Since I need to check user status a `PHP` page should do the job and if user is logged-in it returns the `HTML` content.

`is_user_logged_in` function would do the job but I'm confusing how to implement it since I far as I read on plugin development my case doesn't fit neither in `Actions` nor `Filters`. Also do I need to place my own `PHP` page there or this can be done via a built-in `WordPress` page? If both, which one is recommended?

Note that the page address is always the same for all users.

Comment: How are you outputting your content in that page? I'm not sure what do you mean by `HTML page` since WordPress is PHP based.

Comment: For sure I will return `HTML` content from a `PHP` page which is gonna be a built-in `WorPress` page or my own `PHP` page.

Comment: Well then it would be easy to achieve what you want. Use `is_user_logged_in` to check for members, and then `wp_safe_redirect` afterward to redirect non-logged in users to login page.

Comment: The question is how to embed the `PHP` page into `WordPress`. Simply using that functions doesn't work and for making it a `Plugin` this is not what usually `Actions` and `Filters' do. Any `Plugin` sample with similar scenario is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a page after your plugin is activated. Take a look at this:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'insert_page' );

function insert_page(){
    $my_page = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My Page',
      'post_name'     => 'MyPage',
      'post_content'  => 'My page's content.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
      'post_type'     => 'page',
    );
    wp_insert_post( $my_page, '' );
}
```

Then assign your template file to your custom page:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'my_custom_page' );
function my_custom_page( $page_template )
{
    if ( is_page( 'MyPage' ) ) {
        $page_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/MyPage.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

Now, you have your page and your template. In your template, use this code to detect the visitor's status and decide to redirect them or not:

```
<?php 
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) { 
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/wp-login.php')); 
        exit;
    } 
?>
```

After this code you can safely output your content, since the user will be redirected before outputting the content if he/she is not logged in.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks. Then where to set the page unique address (URL)? I want the website works as before installing my `Plugin` and just the new page be added to it.

Comment: You are welcome. `post_name` is the slug of your page, so your page's URL will be like `http://example.com/MyPage`. But i don't understand what do you mean by `added to it`. If your plugin is not installed, then the page will not be created though.

Comment: I meant no other modifications to the rest of website which seems will not happen with your solution.